# How do I extract values from a multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api

I am getting shares prices using the Alpha Vantage API and I am able to get the most recent price easily enough. But I want to get the price from five entries back.

This is the start of the array I am working with

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-02-22",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2021-02-22": {
            "1. open": "118.5000",
            "2. high": "121.1250",
            "3. low": "118.4400",
            "4. close": "120.8600",
            "5. volume": "5838841"
        },
        "2021-02-19": {
            "1. open": "120.7500",
            "2. high": "120.7600",
            "3. low": "118.3800",
            "4. close": "118.9900",
            "5. volume": "6578741"
        },
```

and this is the clunky code I have been using,

which gets the first day,

turns it into a time,

takes seven days off (since they exchange is closed on weekends) and works with the revised date.

```
$getstocksapi = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=".$stock[$x]."&outputsize=compact&apikey=mycode;
$currentprices = file_get_contents($getstocksapi);
$currentprices = json_decode($currentprices,true);
$dateToCheck =($currentprices['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed']);
$oldDateToCheck = strtotime($dateToCheck);
$oldDateToCheck = ($oldDateToCheck  - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
$oldDateToCheck  = date("Y-m-d", $oldDateToCheck);
$dayEnd[$x] = ($currentprices['Time Series (Daily)'][$dateToCheck]['4. close']);
$thenDayEnd[$x] = ($currentprices['Time Series (Daily)'][$oldDateToCheck]['4. close']);
```

Is there a more elegant way, perhaps using array_slice that I can get the most recent closing price and then the one from five entries down?

Comment: isn't the "Time series (Daily)" already in descending order? Then you just need to get the first five elements

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they are in order. Any ideas how I can simply choose the fifth one?

Comment: yes the fifth one will have index 4 so you can use index $currentprices['Time Series (Daily)'][4]['4. close']

Comment: `$dateToCheck =($currentprices['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed']);
$prevFithDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days', strtotime($dateToCheck)));
echo $currentprices['Time Series (Daily)'][$prevFithDay]['4. close'];`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think op means the 5th entry, not the last 5 days?

Comment: I do mean that. My clunky solution give me 7 days ago, but sometimes there is a long weekend so there is no data for that day @AnuratChapanond

Comment: I tried this ['Time Series (Daily)'][4]['4. close']  but it didn't come back with a value. Not sure why.@AnuratChapanond

Comment: Your code in more elegant than mine @AlivetoDie but it still checks it five days ago when what I really want is the fifth day in the array.

Comment: @MarkO'Meara please see the answer for why it did not work and how to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment, the number index does not work because it still does not have number index. To re-index you can use function `array_values()`.

```
$currentprices = json_decode($data, true);
$timeSeriesDaily = array_values($currentprices['Time Series (Daily)']);
```

Then `$timeSeriesDaily` will be the same array but with number index instead and you can access the 5th index with the following.

```
echo $timeSeriesDaily[4]['4. close'];
```